# How to use the settings package's `--settings` when using ArgParse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

**Background:**
Python has a `simple_settings` [package][1] which allows easy import of program settings from an external file. A program someone wrote, used to supply the settings to the program from the commandline as `python prog.py --settings=someFolder.settings`, and the `settings.py` file would be located in `./someFolder`. The person who wrote it, didn't use any argument parser. The `--settings` argument was just detected by the `simple_settings` package.

**Problem that started:**
But when I started using [argparse][2], I was forced by `argparse` to introduce this line `parser.add_argument("-s", "--settings", help="To enter the settings to be used. Use as` python3 thisProg.py --settings=somefolder.settings`")`. Else it'd throw an error that `--settings` is unrecognized.

Problem is, now `simple_settings` cannot find the `--settings` flag anymore. I get an error when I try to access any settings stored in the `settings.py` file.

```
  File "run.py", line 8, in <module>
    from prog import app_logger
  File "/home/user/project/prog/app_logger.py", line 17, in <module>
    prog_fh = logging.FileHandler(settings.LOG_FILE)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simple_settings/core.py", line 95, in __getattr__
    self.setup()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simple_settings/core.py", line 69, in setup
    self._load_settings_pipeline()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simple_settings/core.py", line 76, in _load_settings_pipeline
    strategy = self._get_strategy_by_file(settings_file)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simple_settings/core.py", line 92, in _get_strategy_by_file
    raise RuntimeError('Invalid settings file [{}]'.format(settings_file))
RuntimeError: Invalid settings file [someFolder.settings]
```

**How I tried solving it:**
Wrote a small program to emulate `argv`, but it seems to be the wrong way to do it and does not work.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from simple_settings import settings

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--desk", help="To enter the desk ID. Use as `python3 thisProg.py -d=<ID>`")
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--settings", help="To enter the settings to be used. Use as `python3 thisProg.py --settings=somefolder.settings`")
    args = parser.parse_args()             
    argv = []   
    argv.append(f"--settings={args.settings}")
    serv = settings.RT_SERVICE,
    sec = settings.CACHE_DATA_EXPIRY_SECONDS
```

**settings.py**

```
RT_SERVICE = 'rt'
CACHE_DATA_EXPIRY_SECONDS = 260
LOG_FILE = 'somefile.log'
```

**Question:**
What is the right way to supply the settings to the `simple_settings` program?
[1]: https://pypi.org/project/simple-settings/
[2]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: I assume your definition of `argv` is an attempt to (re)set `sys.argv`? You need to assign to that directly, because `simple_settings` isn't going to look at any globals in *your* module. `import sys; sys.argv = [f"--settings={args.settings}"]` may work (without looking too closely at the source for `simple_settings`).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/drgarcia1986/simple-settings/blob/main/README.rst) for `simple_settings` says that you can create your own instance of `LazySettings` instead of the (pre-made) instance `settings`.

> ```
> from simple_settings import LazySettings
>
>
> settings = LazySettings("settings.development")
> ```

Instead of *you* calling `LazySettings` explicitly, we'll let the `argparse` parser do it for you, using the `setting` argument's `type` keyword argument.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from simple_settings import LazySettings

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--desk")
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--settings", type=LazySettings)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    serv = args.settings.RT_SERVICE,
    sec = args.settings.CACHE_DATA_EXPIRY_SECONDS
```

Whatever option you pass on the command line, `parse_args` will call `LazySettings` on it and assign the resulting value to the `settings` attribute of the `Namespace` object it will return.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like both `argparse` and `simple_settings` consume your arguments in their entirety, so that might be an either/or choice unless you want to hack around it. In order to continue using the `simple_settings` package, it looks like you could take `--settings` as an argument in your arg parser, then pass that argument to instantiate to `LazySettings`, which instantiates your settings in the same way, but from within your script.

Here is what works on my machine...

script.py:

```py
from simple_settings import LazySettings
from argparse import ArgumentParser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--settings", help="To enter the settings to be used. Use as `python3 thisProg.py --settings=somefolder.settings`")
    args = parser.parse_args()             
    settings = LazySettings(args.settings)
    print(settings)
```

foo_settings.py:

```py
FOO_SETTING = True
```

Command line:

```
% python3 script.py --settings foo_settings
<SIMPLE-SETTINGS ({'FOO_SETTING': True})>
```

[Link to `simple_settings` repo which mentions `LazySettings` in this section](https://github.com/drgarcia1986/simple-settings#how-this-works)